# Return data from linked table

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, join, entity-framework-core

I have 3 tables

table 1 = user table

table 2 = staff table

table 3 = userStaff table

userStaff table is the join table that connects the user and staff table.

```
user Table
 
id | firstName  | password
---------------------------
2  | UserOne    | hashed



staff Table

id | firstName  | lastName
---------------------------
3  | sally      | jones


userStaff Table

userID | staffID
---------------------------
2      | 3
```

I have created a method that inputs the user id and it should return back the staff table corresponding to the staffId linked to the userID. In this case, I want to insert the user id of 2 and get back the information of staff id 3, therefore receiving back " id = 3, firstName = Sally, lastName = jones".

This is the code I tried to use

```
public async Task<UserStaff> GetUserLinkStaff(int id)
{
    var staff = await _context.UserStaffs
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserId == id)
    .Include(s => s.staffs);

    return staff;
}
```

However, I get an error message which says "Task' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no accessible extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Schedular.API]csharp(CS1061)"

What is the correct LINQ query I should use?

Comment: Look at the types! `FirstOrDefaultAsync` returns a `Task<UserStaff>` which doesn't have an `Include` extension method. `Include` is an extension method on `IQueryable<T>`. Of course, you could define an include method for `Task<T>` but you won't have much luck implementing it. `Include` modifies the query but you are trying to use it on the result of a query which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct LINQ query I should use?

To solve it, just change your code as follow:

```
var staff = await _context.UserStuffs.Include(o => o.Stuff)
                  .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserId == id);
```

When using `Include` to get the associated data, you should **first perform the `Include` operation after the `DbSet`**, then return the associated data collection and **get the specific data by `FirstOrDefaultAsync` method after `Include`**.

I suggest you read [this article](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/querying-in-ef-core.aspx) to understand the usage of `Include` in ef core.

Here is the test result:

[image]